# Android: How to only rotate the drawable part of an imageView?

Tags: android, background, rotation, imageview, drawable

I have an ImageView object where both its Background and drawable attributes are set.
I need to animate the drawable part of the ImageView while the background stay still.

I can't find a way to do it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_popup_sync_1"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animId));

Both the drawable and the background are rotating at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

Set the background to a separate layout that sits behind the `ImageView`.  Put both into a `RelativeLayout` where the background `View` is aligned to the `ImageView` by left, right, top, and bottom so that the background stays within the image's bounds.  Then you can rotate the image freely.

EDIT:

Better yet, but the `ImageView` inside a layout and set the layout to `WRAP_CONTENT`.  Set the layout's background to your background image.

Comment: No I can't change my layout... I'm using an ActionBar component and I don't want to override the layout. I just want to know if I can exclude the background from the rotation dynamically or from the anim script...

It seems that the android:drawable attribute in my anim xml has no effect